# Mongoose model methods - create document if unique

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm new to `MongoDB` and `Mongoose`. I'm using it with my Node project (with Express), and I'm trying to keep everything organized and separated. For example, I'm trying to keep all the database queries in each model file. This way all other files could simply use `User.createNew({ fields })` and a new user will be created.

I need each user to be unique (based on their usernames), and I'm not sure exactly where to keep this functionality. I set `unique: true` in the Schema but upon reading Mongoose's documentation, they stated that `unique` is not real validation (or something about how validation should happen beforehand). So my main problem is how to create a static method to create a new user, and also validate this user doesn't exist beforehand. I could implement all of this in one static method:

```
userSchema.statics.createUser = function (username, ..., cb) {
    this.findOne({ username }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return new this({
                username,
                ...
            }).save(cb);
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(new Error("User already exists!"));
        }
    });
};
```

I'm pretty confused with the whole `cb` function and what I'm supposed to pass to it. 
After reading other posts about validation, I realized I could also do something like this:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        validate: function (val, fn) {
            this.find({ username: val }, function (err) {
                fn(err || true);
            });
        },
        message: function (props) {
            `Username '${props.value}' already exists.`;
        },
    },
    ...
```

Also here I'm confused about what `fn` accepts and what it even does (I found an answer similar to this with no explanation online).

In the end, I would like to use this model in a controller to create a new user, like this

```
User.createNew({ username: "example", ...})
    .then(doc => console.log("User was created: " + doc))
    .catch(err => console.error) // The error is something custom like "This user already exists"
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you using callbacks or promises or async-awaits ?

Comment: I use promises or async-awaits

Comment: You can create an unique index on `username` & if DB throws an error you're show user name already exists in UI if not you can say user is successfully stored ! This is simple & can be done in one transaction rather than doing validations with multiple DB calls ! Is this something that you're looking for ?